# Spark tuning for Elasticsearch - how to increase Index/Ingest throughput

Tags: scala, hadoop, elasticsearch, apache-spark

Would like to know the relation between Spark executors, cores and Elasticsearch batch size and how to tune Spark job optimally to get better index throughput.

I have 3.5B data in Parquet format and I would like to ingest them to Elasticsearch and I'm not getting more than 20K index rate. Sometimes I got 60K-70K but it comes down immediately and the average I got was around 15K-25K indexes per second.

Little bit more details about my input:

- Around 22,000 files in Parquet format
- It contains around 3.2B records (around 3TB in size)
- Currently running 18 executors (3 executors per node)

Details about my current ES setup:

- 8 nodes, 1 master and 7 data nodes
- Index with 70 shards
- Index contains 49 fields (none of them are analyzied)
- No replication
- "indices.store.throttle.type" : "none"
- "refresh_interval" : "-1"
- es.batch.size.bytes: 100M (I tried with 500M also)

I'm very new in Elasticsearch so not sure how to tune my Spark job to get better performance.

Comment: have you verified that es isn't a bottleneck here? cpu? disk?
ps: we stopped to use refresh_interval of -1 and reverted it to 30 sec for some reason(I think throughput started to deteriorate with -1 at some point)

Comment: @IgorBerman Yes, I checked CPU & disk and they were normal. Haven't tried using refresh_interval to 30s during this ingest as they suggested to change it to "-1" during large bath ingest. Wondering how it's related to ingest/index performance!